# Single constraint with multiple conditions in Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was solving the following question:

> Find the dimensions of the rectangle of largest area that can be inscribed in: the region in the first quadrant bounded by $x=0$, $y=0$, and $y=1-\frac{x}{3}$

I set up the system as:
$\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$
$g(x,y)=0$

Where $g(x,y)=y-1-\frac{x}{3}=0$ and $f(x,y)=xy$ (the area of the rectangle).

Now I didn't really take into account the boundaries $y=0$ and $x=0$ however after solving the system I got $y=\frac{1}{2}$ and $x=\frac{3}{2}$ which are obviously located in the first quadrant and match the given boundaries but my question is what if I got a solution not in the first quadrant, how could I take into account the other boundaries directly?

Comment: You would have to simply discard any such extraneous solutions, if they don't belong to the domain.

Comment: How did you decide that the inscribed rectangle must not only be axis-aligned, but also have two of its sides along the coordinate axes? Maybe there’s some other way to fit in a larger rectangle?

Comment: @JesseMadnick Yes there was a typo, fixed now, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @amd How would that be possible in the given constraint?

Comment: The constraint describes a triangular region. There are many other rectangles that fit inside that besides the ones that you’re considering. You could place an edge along the line $y=1-x/3$ instead of just one vertex, for instance. I’m sure that whoever created this exercise meant for you to consider only rectangles that have two sides along the coordinate axes, but my question still remains: how do you know that the maximal-area inscribed rectangle is one of those?